# How to list only one line in log if it contains the same string on several lines?

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have a .log file as a result from an **sfv** check.
It contains mostly `OK`, but some `Failed` and some `Not Found`.

I have used

```
findstr /v "OK" "sfv.Log" > "Sfv.Replace.Log"
```

to only get the erroneous files/folders.

But it still leaves me with heaps of corrupt files in the same folders, so the log is still long.

Is there an easy way (batch) that I can only get one line per folder?

For example I would like for the log lines

```
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE14_15_07.swf
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_05_01.flv
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_05_02.flv
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_06_01.flv
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_06_05.flv
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_06_06.flv
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_08_02.flv
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_08_03.flv
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.18.mp3
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.180.mp3
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.181.mp3
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.182.mp3
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.183.mp3
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.184.mp3
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q3.xml
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q4.xml
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q5.xml
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q6.xml
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q7.xml
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q8.xml
```

the output

```
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE14_15_07.swf
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.18.mp3
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q3.xml
```

This way I can more easily see what specific folders I can replace in a whole.

Comment: If you have a linux machine sitting around then you could `cat /path/to/file |rev|cut -d\/ -f2-|rev|sort -u` (not a great answer but...)

Comment: This is on a windows 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 0):

This filtering task could be achieved for example with following batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
del "Sfv_Replace.log" 2>nul
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V "OK" "sfv.log" 2^>nul') do (
    set "LogLine=%%I"
    set "FileNameWithPath=!LogLine:*CD=CD!"
    for %%J in ("!FileNameWithPath!") do set "FilePath=!FileNameWithPath:\%%~nxJ=!
    set "VariableName=Folder#!FilePath:\=_!
    if not defined !VariableName! (
        echo !LogLine!>>"Sfv_Replace.log"
        set "!VariableName!=1"
    )
)
endlocal
```

The log file `Sfv_Replace.log` is deleted first if still existing from a previous run at all.

Next the console application **FINDSTR** is executed on file `sfv.log` which outputs all lines **not** containing the string `OK` case-sensitive anywhere in the line.

Those lines are processed by outer **FOR** loop which assigns first the entire current line to environment variable `LogLine`.

Everything left of `CD` ... the beginning of each directory path ... is removed from the line from log file to get just name of file with relative path assigned to environment variable `FileNameWithPath` using delayed expansion as required whenever an environment variable is defined/modified within a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` and of which value is referenced in same command block.

All values of `FileNameWithPath` on running the batch file on example lines are:

```
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE14_15_07.swf
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_05_01.flv
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_05_02.flv
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_06_01.flv
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_06_05.flv
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_06_06.flv
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_08_02.flv
CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE19_08_03.flv
CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.18.mp3
CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.180.mp3
CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.181.mp3
CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.182.mp3
CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.183.mp3
CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.184.mp3
CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q3.xml
CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q4.xml
CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q5.xml
CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q6.xml
CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q7.xml
CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q8.xml
```

The inner **FOR** loop is used to get from name of file with relative path just the file name and the file extension which are next removed from name of file with path to get just relative directory path stored in environment variable `FilePath`.

All values of `FilePath` on running the batch file on example lines are:

```
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8542\EN\contents\cnt
 CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd
 CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd
 CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd
 CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd
 CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd
 CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd
 CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5
 CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5
 CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5
 CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5
 CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5
 CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5
```

All backslashes in relative directory path are replaced by underscores and `Folder#` is inserted at beginning to build an environment variable name.

All values of `VariableName` on running the batch file on example lines are:

```
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8542_EN_contents_cnt
Folder#CD8539_Course01_Lesson01_Exi_04_snd
Folder#CD8539_Course01_Lesson01_Exi_04_snd
Folder#CD8539_Course01_Lesson01_Exi_04_snd
Folder#CD8539_Course01_Lesson01_Exi_04_snd
Folder#CD8539_Course01_Lesson01_Exi_04_snd
Folder#CD8539_Course01_Lesson01_Exi_04_snd
Folder#CD0165_Course01_Lesson01_alcap_4_5
Folder#CD0165_Course01_Lesson01_alcap_4_5
Folder#CD0165_Course01_Lesson01_alcap_4_5
Folder#CD0165_Course01_Lesson01_alcap_4_5
Folder#CD0165_Course01_Lesson01_alcap_4_5
Folder#CD0165_Course01_Lesson01_alcap_4_5
```

Last it is checked for current environment variable name if there is an environment variable with that name already defined. The line from log file is ignored if this is the case. Otherwise the line from log file is output with redirection into log file `Sfv_Replace.log` on which it is appended and the environment variable is defined with value `1`.

So finally the file `Sfv_Replace.log` contains for the example lines only:

```
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8542\EN\contents\cnt\FSE14_15_07.swf
NOT FOUND    *****        CD8539\Course01\Lesson01\Exi_04\snd\NO.18.mp3
FAILED       CRC32        CD0165\Course01\Lesson01\alcap_4\5\q3.xml
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

On `2^>nul` the angle bracket `>` is escaped with caret character `^` to be interpreted on parsing **FOR** command line as literal character and later on execution of **FINDSTR** as redirection operator to redirect the error message output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL** to suppress it in case of there is no `sfv.log` on execution of the batch file.